# Eloquent Relationships & Conditional Checking

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm in need of some advice on something I haven't run across before, and while it is a necessary component of a friend's project, I am willing to be flexible in how I should go about it.

In their little museum, they have a staffing and document problem. For several sets of donor types, there are a variety of donor document requirements and what I am trying to do is have the donor type on the donor class reference to many on another table which lays out the required documents of that donor type and what type of required they are (either optional, but recommended or straight up required).

At the moment these are my donor model fields:

- id
- lastName
- firstName
- donorType
- docStatus

And the relationship to the donorRequiredDocs model is:

```
public function donorRequiredDocs(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\donorRequiredDocs', 'donorTypeID', 'donorType');
    }
```

My donorRequiredDocs table is setup as such:

- id
- donorTypeID
- requireType (optional, required)
- docType (letter, agreement, etc - but in an INT which references another table)

Now say I have this example:

I am a donor, and my donorType is 1, and 1's are required to have the following documents:

- Agreement
- Letter of Approval
- Notary Required SEM

and are recommended but not required to have:

- Photograph of Donation
- Statement of Account

And I go to donate an object to the museum, after they select my name and record for the new donation which would use my donor table `id` to pull up the model information they have on me. I want the the donation record `docStatus` to remain NULL or 0 until at the very least, the donation record has a relationship with one of each of the three above document types before it can be set to 1.

In this case the donation model is setup as such:
- id
- title
- donorID

```
public function documents(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\donationAttachment', 'donation_id', 'id');
    }
```

And the donationAttachment model is setup as such:

- id
- title
- docType (which uses the same numbering system as the `donorRequiredDocs` table field reference)
- donation_id
- created_at
- updated_at

In the end, besides automatically changing the status once the project determines that the donation has at least one of each of the required documents, I'd like to print it out on the blade until all requirements have been met.

If there is something I missed, I'm happy to post it, I'm just not sure about how to go about this and would appreciate any and all help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Addressing the Relationships only, I think that the the DonorType to Documents relation is really a [Many to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship.

Comment: Aha - Right you are, and while it is just the relationships, everything helps so thanks!